# Kerberos Implementation in Django

Tags: django, ldap, single-sign-on, kerberos

How do i implement an Kerberos SSO in Django?

I am new to Django and need something like a Documentation or Tutorial on how to integrate KErberos and LDAP as SSO in a Django app. I've searched now for a long time and did not find any complete or reasonable solution.